# MySQL get data from three tables using one id

Tags: mysql, select

I have three different tables, which have following structure:

#### Food

```
ID | title
---+----------
1  | sandwich
2  | spaghetti
```

#### Ingridients

```
ID  | food_reference | type | location | bought
----+----------------+------+----------+----------
100 | 1              | ham  | storeA   | 11-1-2013
101 | 1              | jam  | storeB   | 11-1-2013
102 | 2              | tuna | storeB   | 11-6-2013
```

#### Tags

```
ID  | food_reference | tag 
----+----------------+-----
1000| 1              | Tag
1001| 1              | Tag2  
1002| 2              | fish
```

and using one select I want to get all information from these three tables (title,type,location,bought,tag) for one specific ID.
I have tried something like

```
SELECT food.*,ingridients.*,tags.* FROM food  
            JOIN ingridients
                ON :id=ingridients.food_reference
            JOIN tags
                ON :id=tags.food_reference
            WHERE id=:id
```

BUT this query returns for id=1 only one row from ingridients and tags even though there are two matching rows (ham and jam, Tag and Tag2). Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried LolCoder's solution, but I still got only one result, even though in fiddle it seems to work. However I tried  :

```
 SELECT F.*, group_concat(I.type), group_concat(I.location), 
   group_concat(I.bought), group_concat(T.tag) 
 FROM feeds F 
 INNER JOIN ingridients I 
   ON :id = I.food_reference
 INNER JOIN tags T
   ON :id=T.food_reference
 WHERE F.id=:id
```

This finds data from ALL matching rows, but several times, i.e. I get (for id=1)
 sandwich,ham,ham,ham,jam,jam,jam,tag,tag,tag,tag2,tag2,tag2

EDIT2: magic happened and LolCoder's solution works, so thank you :-)

Comment: 'id' is ambigious, as it is present in all tables. You might need to use `food.id` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT food.*,ingridients.*,tags.* FROM food  
            JOIN ingridients
                ON food.id=ingridients.food_reference
            JOIN tags
                ON food.id=tags.food_reference
            WHERE food.id=1
```

Check [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8668fc/3)

Answer (score -2):

use alias with joins as.column name